# A workaround for third party cookies on Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, cross-domain, crossdomain-request.js

I'm trying to get JSON data from an API I created on **domainA.com** to show at **domainB.com** - I'm using third party cookies and it's working fine on Chrome but not on Safari due to strict restrictions. I've tried using an iframe and it still doesn't work on Safari. Can anyone help me out? I want a fix that will work on all browsers. Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: If you have created the API you're calling, then you have to configure it so as to accept cross-domain requests and not send a CORS issue error.

Comment: @JeremyThille It's configured to accept cross-domain requests and it's working fine on Chrome. It's having issues with Safari. The user has to allow third-party cookies before it works.